# how to create a dict of dict of dict of dataframes from list of file paths?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, for-loop, listdir

I have a list of file paths that I want to convert into data frames.

Here is what the files look like

[image]

To better help organize it I would like to have a dict where the key is the dates, and the values are a dict where their keys are the names and they have a dict where keys are results, sales, team, and the values are a dataframe of the file.

I hope I explained it well.

```
2022-03-23_John_result_data.csv
2022-03-23_John_sales_data.csv
2022-03-23_John_team_data.csv
2022-03-23_Lisa_result_data.csv
2022-03-23_Lisa_sales_data.csv
2022-03-23_Lisa_team_data.csv
2022-03-23_Troy_result_data.csv
2022-03-23_Troy_sales_data.csv
2022-03-23_Troy_team_data.csv
2022-03-25_Bart_result_data.csv
2022-03-25_Bart_sales_data.csv
2022-03-25_Bart_team_data.csv
```

**EDIT**

Sorry for the edit but assume the file name could be '2022-03-23_John love [23]_result_data.csv'] forgot to add this case where they could have a space between the names.

Comment: could you include this list as text, not image and include your expected output?

Comment: just did hope that helps. @enke

Comment: for the innermost dictionary, do you want a list of dataframes?

Comment: yeah, the end values should be a dateframe of the file. For example, dic['2022-03-23']['John']['sales'] should be a dateframe of the file "2022-03-23_John_sales_data.csv" @enke

Comment: so for `2022-03-23_John love [23]_result_data.csv`, should the name be `John` or `John love`

Comment: the name would be 'John love [23]'. Because whats between "_" after the date "2022-03-23" and before "_result_data.csv" is the name or ID. Sorry for the poor explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably iterate over the file names and do multiple `dict.setdefault`s (or use a defaultdict), eg:

```
filenames = ['2022-03-23_John_result_data.csv']

dfs = {}
for filename in filenames:
    date, name, category, _ = filename.split('_', 3)
    dfs.setdefault(date, {}).setdefault(name, {})[category] = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

Or using a `defaultdict`...

from collections import defaultdict

```
dfs = defaultdict(dict)
```

Then your `dfs.setdefault(...)` line becomes:

```
dfs[date][name][category] = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

Comment: shoot assume the filenames = ['2022-03-23_John love [23]_result_data.csv']. Sorry I did not take this name type into account.

Comment: @enke please take a look at the edit I forgot to take into account space in the name

Comment: @TroyMcClure8998 I don't see how the space affects anything here? As long as you've not got rogue `_`s which are what're being used to split the components

Comment: @JonClements I think I resolved the error. But when I do dfs['2022-03-25']['John'] it returns {'category': None}.   But that was resolved when I did  dfs.setdefault(date, {}).setdefault(name, {category})[]. But the dataframes are still nonetype.

Comment: Have you used the latest code? I had a typo originally... check you're using `dfs.setdefault(date, {}).setdefault(name, {})['category'] = pd.read_csv(filename)` and not what I had originally

Comment: @JonClements when I do dfs.setdefault(date, {}).setdefault(name, {}).setdefault(category) = pd.read_csv(filename). I get the error "cannot assign to function call here. Maybe you meant '==' instead of '='?"

Comment: That's the old typo'd code... look at the comment above and the amended answer (from half hour ago :p)... use that code...

Comment: @JonClements worked like a charm.  spend the whole morning on this. thank you so much!! Just edit and remove the string from category in dfs.setdefault(date, {}).setdefault(name, {})['category'].   As it gave me an error. Sorry not error but changes the key name from category to "sales, results and team. Which is cleaner,

Comment: @TroyMcClure8998 ooops sorry - I didn't mean to `category` as a string (have edited again to update)... must be getting tired - been at the keyboard all day :p